# Is there a way to overwrite HDD data so that it looks like an accident?

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

Recently I got a relative's laptop due to the fact they thought it was broken. This included the hard drive. Anyway, me being a curious fool, I decided to look through it and found some pretty sensitive stuff about their personal life. Now they've realized, they want it back to have a professional see if any data could be recovered.

I know all the stuff I viewed has time stamps and I also accidentally loaded some data onto the drive. Are there any ways to remove my traces of being a snooper without looking too suspicious?

**More info:** The HDD was not given to me in perfectly working order. Using testdisk, I determined just the boot sector had an error, hence them assuming it was broken. It was also making some clicking noises, so theres a possible hardware error too.

Comment: Wiping it clean with secure erase, or physically damaging the HDD are the two I can think of...

Comment: I guess that's one of my last options. Since they want to turn it into a professional, I would assume he would be curious why it was so cleanly erased. I'm pretty sure harddrives dont neatly rewrite themselves due to a hardware error.

Comment: This is a terrible idea.  Just tell them you fixed it (or found the data there when you plugged it in to reformat it), saved them a lot of money and bask in the glory of your success. No one's going to really look closely at the last access times.

Comment: I would love to do this, but in the process of looking around I noticed one of the folders that I previously visited had vanished. Couldn't find any trace of it while looking in ubuntu's disk information program. I would find that mildly hard to explain, especially since it was the folder with most of the sensitive information.

Comment: @Oman So don't; Tell them you got it working, and briefly tested a random file, if you can save this person money by preventing them from spending money on someone looking at it for 5 minutes only to tell them exactly what I suggested go ahead...

Comment: I'm with Ramhound and Journeyman Geek here... this is a none technical person, they won't understand timestamps, etc, or probably even care now that they have their data, and you would be doing them a huge favor and saving them money to return the drive, tell them you did the best you could and it seems OK now, and leave it at that. Plus there is a factor of honesty, doing the right thing, and taking responsibility for your actions, lying just leads to more lies and usually becomes a never ending hole, fess up and be an adult.

Comment: Computer guys are like a doctors, can see a lot of private stuff, but it is matter of honesty to keep mouth shut about what you saw. Check SMART status of hdd and if there is errors, get another new hdd and clone existing disk to a new one. Do what you supposed to do and next time avoid browsing what you shouldn't and even if need to, be a honest person, keep some1 secret as you never saw it, doing monkey business will bother you for a long time that you did some dirty trick to your close ones .

Comment: I am also with Ramhound, Journeyman Geek and Acejavelin. Be the hero, they didn't think they could get any data anyway, so what ever you are able to recover, I am sure they would be grateful. Be honest, it always works best in the end. Don't dig a hole.

Comment: And a professional is not going to look close enough (or even care for that matter) that you may have lost the data they are looking for, and I am pretty sure using data recovery software, that folder you lost could be brought back, it is still there, as long as nothing was ever written to the drive.

Comment: With clicking noises the drive may fail anytime. I would blame hardware for folder disappearance and the boot sector error in the first place. If I were you I would even save a `ddrescue` copy. If by any chance the drive fails shortly afterwards, this nonchalant statement could make you a greater hero: 'I may still have the binary copy somewhere, standard procedure, let me look for it.' In my opinion it *is* standard procedure. I make such a copy even if I'm about to reinstall somebody else's Windows and they claim they saved all their photos etc. – just in case. It requires disk space though.

Comment: I appreciate all the advice, I'll probably just copy it all down onto a flash drive and tell them I recovered most of the stuff

Comment: If you still worry about access/modification time stamps you can change it with [BFC](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bulk_file_changer.html) and clean your activity history with  [CleanAfterMe](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/clean_after_me.html) since i think you would return hard drive to the owner anyway